# Minimise $\sum \left\lvert x_j \right\rvert^2 + \sum \left\lvert y_j \right\rvert^2$ subject to the constraints $\sum x_j = 1$ and $\sum y_j = 0$.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, inner-products, maxima-minima

Let $X := \mathbb{C}^n$ with the inner product defined by
$$
\big\langle \left( x_1, \ldots, x_n \right) \, , \, \left( y_1, \ldots, y_n \right) \big\rangle := \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \overline{y_j}. 
$$
Let the set $M$ be defined by
$$
M := \left\{ \,  \left( x_1, \ldots, x_n \right) \in \mathbb{C}^n \colon \sum_{j=1}^n x_j = 1 \, \right\}. 
$$
Then how to find a vector (or vectors) of minimum norm in $M$?

In other words, how to solve the following version of the above minimisation problem?

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n$ be some real variables. Then how to minimize
$$
f \left( x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n \right) := \sum_{j=1}^n \left\lvert x_j \right\rvert^2 + \sum_{j=1}^n \left\lvert y_j \right\rvert^2,
$$
subject to the constraints
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n  x_j = 1 \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad \sum_{j=1}^n y_j = 0? 
$$

I've not much of an idea of how to even start my solution. Hence no attempt shown.

I'd appreciate an answer that is as detailed and elementary as possible.

Comment: Set $y_j=0$ for all $j\le n$. This then becomes a case of minimising $\sum x_j^2$ such that $\sum x_j=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum value is $\frac1  n$. By Cauchy Scwarz inequlity $|\sum x_i|^{2}\leq n\sum |x_i|^{2}$ which shows that $\sum |x_i|^{2}+\sum |y_i|^{2} \geq \frac 1 n$. This lower bound is attained when $x_i=\frac 1 n$ for each $i$  and $y_i=0$ for each $i$.